# Updating only certain values of data frame based on match

Tags: r, match, lapply

I'm trying to update a variable (`popsnp`) in a higher scope within an `lapply`, on the basis of a match. I can't quite figure out the syntax for updating the values though, what I have currently overwrites any previously existing values with `NA`:

```
lapply(1:22, function(i){
  in.name<-paste("/data/mdp14aps/ld/chr", i, ".ld", sep="")
  out.name<-paste("/data/mdp14aps/R/ldatachr", i, ".rda", sep="")
  ldata<-read.csv(in.name, sep="", header=TRUE,
                  colClasses=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"NULL"))
  freq<-count(ldata, c("SNP_A", "CHR_A", "BP_A"))

  #the part I'm not sure about
  popsnp$chrom<<-freq[match(popsnp$marker, freq$SNP_A),2]
  popsnp$position<<-freq[match(popsnp$marker, freq$SNP_A),3]
  popsnp$freq<<-freq[match(popsnp$marker, freq$SNP_A),4]

  save(ldata,file=out.name)
  rm(ldata, freq)
})
```

I want to preserve the values I'm setting between iterations of `lapply` so I end up with `popsnp` containing *all* values of `chrom`, `position` and `freq`, not just the last iteration.

I feel like this should be straightforward, but I'm still somewhat unfamiliar with R.

A toy example:

```
test<-data.frame(A = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), B = c(rep(NA,5)))
test1<-data.frame(A = c("a", "b"), B = c(1, 2))
test2<-data.frame(A = c("c", "d", "e"), B = c(3, 4, 5))

test$B<-test1[match(test$A, test1$A), 2]
test$B<-test2[match(test$A, test2$A), 2]
```

I want `test$B` to have the values from 1-5 in it.

Comment: Can you simplify your question to the essential problem with a reproducible example?

Comment: try to avoid `<<-` because it can lead to nasty bugs, besides this I hav no idea where popsnp chomes from what it looks like and what you are trying to do, a simple for-loop instead of lapply would work without the `<<-` operator and would solve your problem, but like plafort said please simplify and explain

Comment: Also a little unclear why you would intentionally set colClasses to NA/NULL. Never seen that before. Typically, you would set them to character/numeric.

Comment: I've added a reproducible example. Wrt the colClasses, I was basically trying to exclude a column of the file I was importing. As for the lapply vs for loop, I kept reading that you should avoid loops in R...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update for your Toy Example

You need to subset both sides of your assignment, and also convert your conditions to logical subsetting vectors.

```
logical1 <- !is.na(test1[match(test$A, test1$A),2]) # TRUE/FALSE
logical2 <- !is.na(test1[match(test$A, test2$A),2])

test[t1,] <- test1[t1,] # selects only TRUE rows
test[t2,] <- test2[t2,]
```

I recommend you look at each element individually so you can see what's happening.

---

#### Previously...

I'm not exactly sure I understand what you're example is trying to accomplish. So I'm going to provide you with a toy example of subsetting:

```
dat <- data.frame(
 A = sample(letters[3:26],26,replace = TRUE)
 B = runif(26)
)

# Replaces everything in column B where column A == "a"
dat[dat$a == "c", "B"] <- 1

# dat$A == "c" returns a TRUE/FALSE vector, "B" returns column "B".
```

Best practice is to always use TRUE / FALSE conditions while subsetting to avoid future errors. You could subset by row number, but it ALWAYS gets messy.

It's important to note that your use of `<<-` pushes your change of the variable to the parent environment, outside of the scope of your function. This can lead to unexpected results in the future. It's better to supply the variable you want to change and then return it again at the end of your manipulation function. This way you have a clear sequence of events.

```
myfun <- function(x,y) { 
  # ... do stuff to y
  return(y)
}

y <- myfun(x,y)
```

#### Final Update

Lastly, with respect to dropping unnecessary columns. Typical practice is to drop them after import by name (best practice) or reference number (changes in data break this).

```
ldata[c('col1','col2',...)] <- NULL # drop
```